# what are the difference between "at this time tomorrow / yesterday / next week..." and "this time tomorrow / yesterday / next week..."?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I saw this sentence "**Yesterday at this time, I was sitting at my desk at work.**" in [this page](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastcontinuous.html)

And then, I also saw this sentence "**This time tomorrow I will be waiting at the doctor’s office.**" in [this page](https://www.englishgrammar.org/future-continuous-tense-2/)

My question is that:

what are the difference between "**at this time tomorrow / yesterday / next week...**" and "**this time tomorrow / yesterday / next week...**"?

**Are they the same?**

In [the dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/time_1?q=time),

> **time**: [uncountable] the time shown on a clock in minutes and hours
>
> *The time is now half past ten*
>
> *This time tomorrow I'll be in Canada.*

also [in another dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/at-this-time)

> **at this time**
>
> (American English) at this particular moment
>
> *The president said his actions were ‘the right ones at this time’.*

It seems like "**at this time**" is an idiom

Comment: "This time tomorrow" is a time reference. "*At* this time tomorrow" is a pointer to a time reference.

Answer (score 1):

In your example phrase

> *(at)* this time tomorrow
>   tomorrow *(at)* this time

have the same meaning and are interchangeable.

I'm not sure if it rates as an idiom, but the "**at**" may be dropped as often happens when phrases are commonly and often used.

The phrase is a semi-specific time reference, maybe not as exact as

> Tomorrow at 10:00 (assuming it is currently 10:00) I will be at the doctor's.

but more exact than just using

> Tomorrow I will be at the doctor's.

It tends to have the meaning of "**around this time**".

Comment: [Cambridge dictionary entry for time](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/time) shows use of both "this time" and "at this time". "Just think, this time (= at the same particular point during) next week we'll be in Aruba." "It’s unusual to get snow at this time of year." The second sentence isn't the exact same usage but it's very similar.